# Differentiating the trace with respect to a parameter

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

Let us define a matrix $A(\rho)$ where $\rho \in \mathbb R$. Is there a formula for the derivative of $$\mbox{tr} \left( A(\rho)^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} A(\rho) \right)$$ with respect to $\rho$? Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you ! I got it. I managed to compute the derivative of the inverse and the rest was easy.

Answer (score 0):

well, the trace of a matrix $M$ is
\begin{equation}
\text{tr}(M)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}
\end{equation}
so if $M$ is a differentiable function of a variable $\rho$, i guess we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\rho}\text{tr}(M(\rho))=\sum_{i=1}^n a'_{ii}(\rho)=\text{tr}\left(\frac{d}{d\rho}M(\rho)\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (t) := \mbox{tr} \left( \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \right)$$

Hence,

$$f (t + {\rm d} t) = \cdots = f (t) + \mbox{tr} \left( \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \ddot{\mathrm A} (t) \right) {\rm d} t - \mbox{tr} \left( \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \right) {\rm d} t$$

and, thus,

$$\dot f (t) = \mbox{tr} \left( \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \ddot{\mathrm A} (t) \right) - \mbox{tr} \left( \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \right)$$

Comment: $$\dot f (t) = \mbox{tr} \left( \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \ddot{\mathrm A} (t) \right) - \mbox{tr} \left( \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \dot{\mathrm A} (t) \left(\mathrm A (t)\right)^{-1} \right)$$ is the correct answer

Comment: @Ajmal Given the cyclicality of the trace operator, isn't that equivalent to my answer?

Comment: ahh yes you are right !